# select distinct with parent-child and return boolean for at least one child with a value?

Tags: sql-server

I am currently searching for orders that have at least one orderline (product) with a certain boolean set: 
- the product is a subscription product
- the product is a setup product

If one of the orderlines has this value set to 1, I want to return this in the query per DISTINCT order ID.

This does not seem to work for me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [ORDER].[order_id]
                ,[ORDERLINE].[is_subscription] AS hasSubArticles
                ,[ORDERLINE].[is_setup] AS hasSetupArticles
        FROM [ORDER] 
        LEFT JOIN [ORDERLINE]
        ON [ORDER].[order_id] = [ORDERLINE].[f_order_id]
        WHERE [G_ORDER].[status] = 1
        ORDER BY [ORDER].[order_id]
                ,[ORDERLINE].[is_subscription] AS hasSubArticles
                ,[ORDERLINE].[is_setup] AS hasSetupArticles
```

When I check the returned records, I receive duplicate ORDER records:

```
order_id hasSubArticles hasSetupArticles
----------------------------------------
17804    NULL           NULL
17804    1              0
```

I want to return only 1 record per order ID, thus this isn't working for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not filtering out line items that are not subscription or setup articles.

Comment: Also, the order coming back with null values does not have a related  record in the table you left joined on, or at least in the filter you placed on it using the where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Distinct` does not work for your requirement. `MAX`, `Min` functions are not allowed to use with `bit` type.  You could use `Group by` and `SUM` like this

```
SELECT  
    [ORDER].[order_id]
    ,CASE   WHEN SUM( CASE WHEN [ORDERLINE].[is_subscription] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
    END AS hasSubArticles
    ,CASE   WHEN    SUM( CASE WHEN [ORDERLINE].[is_setup] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 
                THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
    END hasSetupArticles
FROM [ORDER] 
LEFT JOIN [ORDERLINE]
ON [ORDER].[order_id] = [ORDERLINE].[f_order_id]
WHERE [G_ORDER].[status] = 1
GROUP BY [ORDER].[order_id]
```